# Rails3, setting the value of 'active_record.default_timezone' breaks time parsing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, timezone

I have code like this:

```
hh = History.select("STRFTIME(\"%Y-%m-%d %H\", created_at) AS created_at, ..., count(*) AS count_all")
puts hh[0].created_at
```

If `config.active_record.default_timezone` isn't set that code works correctly, otherwise `hh[0].created_at = nil`.

Why?

And how I can fix it?

Comment: The problem occurs only for Sqlite3. For Postgres it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this in the console:

```
History.select("STRFTIME(\"%Y-%m-%d %H\", created_at) AS created_at, ..., count(*) AS count_all").to_sql
```

This will show you the output being sent to Sqlite3 and then you can check that against what SQL items it expects. In your case the `select` is valid for the Postgres SQL flavor but not Sqlite3